# catch missing method call with javascript proxy

Tags: javascript

How can I get this code to work. I want to intercept all missing method calls on my function, and redirect them to a "catch all" kind of method on said function.

```
var foo=function(){
  this.bar=function(){
    return "found!";
  }
  this.not_found=function(){
    return "method not found.";
  }
}

var p = new Proxy(foo, {
    get: function (target, prop) {
        if (Object.keys(target).indexOf(prop) !== -1) {
          // should call existing method.
            //return target[prop]; <-- does not work.
        }else{
          // here i want to call "not_found() on foo() if prop doesnt exist
        }
    }
});

console.log(p.bar()); // should print out: found!;
console.log(p.foo()); // should print out: method not found;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: foo is a function. it is not object. create object using new foo() and then it will work. Proxy work on object not on function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a function. As [deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149361/deepak) said, if you create an object from it, it will work:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.bar = function () {
        return "found!";
    }
    this.notFound = function () {
        return "method not found.";
    }
};

var p = new Proxy(new Foo, {
    get: function (target, prop) {
        if (Object.keys(target).indexOf(prop) !== -1) {
            return target[prop];
        } else {
            return target['notFound'];
        }
    }
});

console.log(p.bar()); // prints: found!;
console.log(p.foo()); // prints: method not found;
```

Since `Foo` is acting like a constructor, I wrote it with a capital letter. Also, the convention is to use camel case for names. Took the liberty to change these.

A slightly cleaner version (using `in`):

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.bar = function () {
        return "found!";
    }
    this.notFound = function () {
        return "method not found.";
    }
};

var foo = new Foo();

var p = new Proxy(foo, {
    get: function (target, prop) {
        if (prop in target) {
            return target[prop];
        } else {
            return target['notFound'];
        }
    }
});

console.log(p.bar()); // prints: found!;
console.log(p.foo()); // prints: method not found;
```

Comment: Updated the answer with a slightly cleaner version using `in`. You can also use `hasOwnProperty`, depending on what you need.

Comment: by adding "new" will the foo object not be recreated/new instance everytime i call a method on p?

Comment: Right. You can do `var foo = new Foo;` before calling `new Proxy` and pass it `foo` instead of `new Foo`.

Comment: yes i think that would be better, as i also want to pass in some parameters to foo() at first.

Comment: (cant seem to tag you?) one more question: How can I in the "notFound" function, access the name of the attempted fuction called. in this case "foo()" and also its params. i have tried to pass both target and prop in different ways, but no luck.